# Kuratowski's theorem on Planar graphs

Tags: planar-graphs

I've got an exercise that I've been battling for 5 hours to solve. There is a picture of the graph below. I am sure that I can't find a K5 as a minor since every vertex has 3 edges leaving. I tried so long to find a K3,3 minor and failed. What is the correct approach? I also strongly believe that it is not planar graph.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2625442/120540 (but no upvoted/accepted answers)

Comment: It's a duplicate. You can close/delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the edges $\{EG\}$ and $\{FH\}$. Then you can do the following:

[image]

Comment: I forgot to add lettering to my original graph. Could you please edit your answer so I can understand where is the K3,3 minor that I still don't see?

Comment: I edited the graph in the question, now it is appropriate.